# Saving python script in executable format

Tags: python-2.7, executable-format

How do I save the python script that I'm working on in executable format in a specific folder? Saving manually is not allowed. The code for saving must be within the script itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some further clarity about what you're trying to do.

Comment: My homework consists of three tasks.
First, I have to create a new directory/folder. I've handled that already. Second, we were asked to create a python script involving nested loops. I've done that too. Lastly, the script must be saved in the directory that I created in executable format. It must not be done manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('myexecutable', 'w') as efile:
    efile.write('all my code goes here')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be problematic to copy the entire code and paste inside the parentheses since there would be indentions and other stuff?

Comment: Not if you escape it properly with the triple quotes